# Show multiple messages for different form fields using ng-messages

Tags: angularjs, validation, ng-messages

Is it possible to use ng-messages with angular 1.3 and show validation summary on the top with error messages for different fields?

```
<div ng-messages="myForm.$error">
    <div ng-message="required">Need to show required error for field 1.</div>
    <div ng-message="required">Need to show required error for field 2.</div>
</div>
```

How can i achieve this ?
All the examples i have seen so far is showing error messages for one single field, not for all the fields in the form.

Do I need to have multiple ng-messages section for each field?

Comment: Do you want to show different messages for a form field based on any criteria?

Comment: No, i want to show all the errors for multiple fields as a summary.

Comment: let me put my understanding here. You have a form, in which you have multiple fields, once the user submits the form you want to shoe all the messages at one place. is my understanding correct?

Comment: Yes. please see my edit above.

Comment: Please have alook at the link http://plnkr.co/edit/iSFp3n4PSDTM6pRofXc2?p=preview
Is this you are expecting?

Comment: This example doesn't use ng-messages.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I wanted to style the whole summary block as one. So i ended up doing this.

```
<div class="error-summary" ng-show="myForm.$submitted && myForm.$invalid">
    <p ng-show="myForm.field1.$error.required">Field 1 is required.</p>
    <p ng-show="myForm.field2.$error.required">Field 2 is required.</p>
</div>
```

I was hoping to do something similar to this using ng-messages.

Answer (score 3):

How about this?

```
<div ng-messages="myForm.field1.$error">
    <div ng-message="required">Need to show required error for field 1</div>
</div>
<div ng-messages="myForm.field2.$error">
    <div ng-message="required">Need to show required error for field 2</div>
</div>
<div ng-messages="myForm.field3.$error">
    <div ng-message="required">Need to show required error for field 3</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you should have multiple `ng-messages`. Please have a look at the below link.

http://plnkr.co/edit/QgNkXKosgcArGZW7WuZO?p=preview

```
<form name="myForm">
  <label>Enter your name:</label>
  <br>
  <input type="text" name="myName1" ng-model="name1" required />
  <br>
  <input type="text" name="myName2" ng-model="name2" required />

  <div ng-messages="myForm.myName1.$error">
    <div ng-message="required">enter name 1</div>
  </div>
  <div ng-messages="myForm.myName2.$error">
    <div ng-message="required">enter name 2</div>
  </div>
</form>
```